# Objective C: How to get access token from web browser to cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, onedrive

Please let me elaborate what I am trying to do.

**What I want to do?**

I am creating a cocoa application that uploads an user files to user's [Onedrive](http://onedrive.live.com) and in order to do that I am requesting for an Access token by launching **the access token URL** in *Safari*.

[https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={APPLICATIONID}&scope=wl.signin+wl.offline_access+onedrive.readwrite&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf](https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=%7BAPPLICATIONID%7D&scope=wl.signin%20wl.offline_access%20onedrive.readwrite&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf)

**Problem**

Now the problem is how will I retrieve the access token from safari to my cocoa app?

In short: How to get one drive access token in Cocoa Application?

Please help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order get access token on Local application you will need to follow given below steps:

1. Login to [dev.onedrive.com](http://dev.onedrive.com) and check YES on **Mobile or desktop client app** option
   [image]
2. Take a browser control in you application and load the access token verify page
3. Add a URL change event for browser control
4. Whenever you get a url starting with **https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf** that has a # and access_token variable than it means you application has received the access from a user.
5. In case user clicks on NO(not providing access) then you will get a url starting with **https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?lc=1033#error=access_denied**

**Note:** The idea is very simple. You will need to monitor URL changes and do the task accordingly.

**P.S:** Keep in mind that the redirect URL for local apps will be https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf